# Find the index of n unique rows with the lowest values

Tags: matlab

I have a *151*-by-*151* matrix `A`. It's a correlation matrix, so there are `1`s on the main diagonal and repeated values above and below the main diagonal.

I'm looking for a way to obtain the indices of `n` many rows with the lowest values.

The number of rows I want to find is fixed at `n`, and the `n` many rows must be unique.

So, for example let's say that:

```
n = 10
```

and data as follows

[image: Part of the matrix]

Row 1 is involved in the lowest correlation (with row/column 6), and also the third lowest correlation (with row/column 9).

That means I've found the indices of three of the rows I need: 1, 6, and 9. However, I don't count row 1 twice, and hence I still need to find the indices of 7 more rows.

I've tried the approach

```
function [smallestNElements smallestNIdx] = getNElements(A, n)
     [ASorted AIdx] = sort(A);
     smallestNElements = ASorted(1:n);
     smallestNIdx = AIdx(1:n);
end
```

which I obtained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140746/how-to-find-the-index-of-the-n-smallest-elements-in-a-vector). However, I think that approach is fundamentally inapplicable because it's meant to apply to a vector. When I apply it to my 2D matrix it just gives the index of the lowest values in the first column.

By lowest I mean lowest in absolute terms and not "closest to zero". Thus `-0.9` is lower than `-0.1`, which in turn is lower than `0.05`.

Comment: What is the goal of your statistical analysis?

Comment: My goal is just to identify those n many people (each row in the correlation matrix is a person) who have the lowest possible - or better yet, negative - correlations with each other.

Comment: Don't you need pairs of people then?

Comment: You might find this function useful: http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/tiedrank.html

Comment: @BillBokeey Yes, we have pairs of people. Each correlation in the matrix was created by considering paired data between two individuals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, get rid of the repeated values by making them `Inf` so that they won't be mistaken for being the lowest values:

```
A1 = tril(A);
A1(A1==0) = Inf;
```

now find the indices of the `n` smallest:

```
[~,idx] = sort(A1(:));
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(A), idx(1:n));
```

That finds the lowest `n` correlation, if you want the `n` rows involved in the lowest correlations without repeating them then

```
[~,idx] = sort(A(:));
[r,c] = ind2sub(size(A), idx);
rows = unique(r,'stable');
result = rows(1:n)
```

Comment: If I set n to 5 and apply your method to the diagrammed correlation matrix I get r = [6,9,8,7,8] and c = [1,1,1,3,3]. That identifies the 5 lowest correlations but it is not clear to me where I can find the 5 rows (in other words, the 5 people) involved in the lowest correlations. Are you able to explain how I can do that?

Comment: When I run that I get [6,9,8,7,10]. It is true that they are the n rows  involved in the lowest correlations without repeating if we consider only the trimmed matrix A1, but in the original matrix A I can see that row 1 has an extremely low correlation. Is there some way to consider that, e.g. by considering rows and columns in A1, or reverting to consider A?

Comment: What happens if you don't remove the upper triangle (i.e. work with `A` and not `AA`)?

Comment: This solution will omit ``correlation = 0`` as possibility.

Comment: @DennisKlopfer not the accepted solution which is to leave off the first two lines. But otherwise yes, the original was flawed. But a correlation of exactly `0` sounds very unlikely if this is from observed data

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
[~, idx] = sort(sum(A));
results = idx(1:n);
```

How this works is the `sum` is taken over the columns of a matrix.  This leaves me with a `1 x columns` vector.  The vector is sorted smallest to largest and the indices are retained.  Then the first `n` number of indices are kept as the result.  Here is the result using your data for `n=4`

```
result = 
    1
    6
    9
    8
```